# Perfoming null-checks while collecting with Collectors.groupingBy

Tags: java, null, java-stream, collectors, groupingby

I have the following piece of code which groups the given entries  (activities, which is `Iterable<activity>`) based on IDs.

For the final result, I want it to return a `Map` of *ID* to *Iterables* of the entries grouped by that *ID*.

For example: `Map<String, Iterables<activity>>`.

Right now, it returns a `Map<String, List<activity>>`.

```
        stream(activities)
            .collect(
                groupingBy(
                    activity -> {
                      if (activity.getID()) {
                        return activity.getID();
                      } else {
                        return activity.getName();
                      }
                    }));
```

I am unable to figure out a way to do this.

Comment: You'll need to study up on the Java type system. A `List` _is_ an `Iterable`.  `Iterable` is just an interface. It's implemented by many of the container types, providing a common way to iterate over all of them. For example, `for` loops accept any `Iterable` as source data.  There's no concrete class called `Iterable`.

Answer (score 0):

There's no such notion in **Java** as [truthy values](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy), which exists in languages like javascript. I.e. `String` can't be resolved into `boolean` automatically (*what your code attempts to do*).

There are multiple ways of how you can check whether the given value is `null` and provide an alternative value.

If `name` attribute is guaranteed to be *non-null* you can use static method `requireNonNullElse()` of the `Objects` utility class:

```
.collect(Collectors.groupingBy(act -> Objects.requireNonNullElse(act.getID(), act.getName()));
```

If `name` attribute is nullable, then you have to provide a default value that will be used in case if both `id` and `name` equal to `null`. Because `null` key is not allowed with `Collectors.groupingBy()` and will result in `NullPointerException` at runtime.

For the case when both field could be `null` I suggest extracting the logic for obtaining the key into a separate method.

```
public static String getKey(Action action) {
    return action.getID() != null ? action.getID() :
         action.getName() != null ? action.getName() : "defaultKey";
}
```

Which can be used inside the *collector* like that:

```
.collect(Collectors.groupingBy(act -> getKey(act)); // or as a method reference MyClass::getKey
```

*Sidenote*: by convention, names of classes in Java should start with a capital letter: `Student`, `Employee`, `Activity`.